# PowerShell connecting to a rest API with a self signed cert.

Tags: powershell, ssl

I am trying to call a rest API on an appliance, however it is using a self signed cert for the https socket. I have tried changing the following in PowerShell

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }
```

But whilst making my call using the following,

```
$uri = 'https://hostname/api/config'
$headers = @{"Authorization"="token apitokengoeshere"}
try {
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
}
catch {
$_.Exception |format-list -force
}
```

but I get the following error still

```
Status         : SendFailure
Response       :
Message        : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected 
error occurred on a send.
Data           : {}
InnerException : System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the 
                transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection       was forcibly closed by the remote host
               at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
               at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
TargetSite     : System.Net.WebResponse 
GetResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)
StackTrace     :    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
                    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
HelpLink       :
Source         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility
HResult        : -2146233079
```

I have even tried installing the Tunable-SSL Powershell module as mentioned in the blog mentioned 
[Here](http://huddledmasses.org/blog/validating-self-signed-certificates-properly-from-powershell/) on a previous question.

Comment: It looks like the device itself may be blocking you

Comment: Doubt it, the call works in Python from the same source to the same host.

Comment: If it's working with Python, why are you trying to then use PowerShell?  No py interpreter on the target host?

Comment: Locked down environment, can't install Python on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simple script which I wrote to check result code status on HTTPS pages with self-signed certs.

Through much googling this is what I ended up with:

```
Add-Type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@ -ea SilentlyContinue -wa SilentlyContinue
```

Then followed by this right before the Invoke-WebRequest call:
`[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy`

Comment: This is the answer...Sort of. I had to do the following also, `[net.Servicepointmanager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` to force PowerShell to use TLS1.2, Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know this is long past it's time but for posterity's sake, the TLS 1.2 thing is a .NET issue.  I suggest you implement the SystemDefaultTLS reg key mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/solving-tls1-problem

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain.

You have two options. First, if you're running Powershell 6.0, you can disregard the certificate all together with the `-SkipCertificateCheck` [switch parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters):

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/p
osts/1' -SkipCertificateCheck
```

NOTE: I don't have Powershell 6.0 to test this out. You might have to splat the parameter. Start with this, splat if this doesn't work.

Second, you can download the certificate from the service, ship it with your script (if you trust it), and when you call the service ensure its certificate matches the trusted one that shipped with your script. A couple of ways you can do this:

```
$certificate = ...load-your-cert...
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/p
osts/1' -Certificate $certificate
```

If the certificate is in your cert store, you can also specify the cert's thumbprint.

Comment: The `...load-your-cert...` part is probably a call to [`Get-PfxCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-pfxcertificate).

Comment: The thumbprint is specified via `-CertificateThumbprint`.